# How can I display js queried results in a webpage

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I have queried my firebase database to count the number of people that have subscribed to topics.  I have received the results in the console.log() and I would like to display the results on a webpage in the div customerNumber. The code below displays the same number next to each topic even though the correct number is diplayed under each topic in the console.log(). How do I correct this?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="rh_topic" title="Title" ></div>
<div class="customerNumber"></div>
```

This is my code in my javascript file.

```
    function countSubscribers () {
    const topics = document.querySelectorAll(".rh_topic");
    topics.forEach(topic => {
        let number = topic.title;
        const ref = firebase.database().ref('topics/' + number);
        ref.once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log(topic.title);
            console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
            let customers = snapshot.numChildren();
            const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('customerNumber');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
                element.textContent = customers;
            });             
        });
    });
}
            
countSubscribers();
```

Answer (score 0):

to simplify, you can just use

```
elements.map((elements, indexEl) => {
  elements.innerText = customers
  return true;
})
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting this error in the console: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: elements.map is not a function"

Comment: elements.map((element, indexEl) => {
  element.innerText = customers
  return true;
})

Wrong on the maped 'elements' remove the 's'.

But i am sure the error is not that,

Are you able to show the the two log: ?
console.log(topic.title);
            console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
the error means that the 'elements' variable is null or undefined
looking at your code at :
<div class="customerNumber"></div>

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('customerNumber');

that means the HTML is not mounted or loaded

is your code called within page load ?

Comment: Did the amendment but still getting the same error. Yes I see both logs. If you look at my code above, a number is being pulled into the element <div class="customerNumber"></div> but it is either the first or the last number because those two are the same. I know that I am supposed to loop through customers and write each number into the element. I just can't seem to structure the loop properly.